# Git Status eating CPU and taking 5s

Tags: git, macos, macos-catalina

I have a fresh install of git on a Catalina MacOS laptop.

In a fairly large repo, a `git status` is taking 5s to return and is consuming 800% of CPU.

Have tried on other mac machines not running Catalina and the issue does not seem to exist.

I have tried with git from Apple and from git directly. It seems that the first execution of the command after a reboot is quick. Every other one beyond that takes time.

```
real    0m0.663s
user    0m0.034s
sys     0m5.458s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to catalina, I have MacOS Catalina and I don't have this issue, but my project is of normal size, not huge and not small.

Comment: What is the size of the repo? Git is slow for large repositories. See [the biggest repository](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/)

Comment: It is a pretty large repo. ~200MB. However, I do not see any delays with git on other machines with the same repo. In addition, the first git status is fast. Subsequent ones are slow. So, I do not think the problem is repo size.

Comment: That's an ... interesting set of time numbers, because the `sys` time is so high without any corresponding `user` time. It's probably worth using some sort of time profiler on it, to see which system calls are churning so hard. See https://gist.github.com/loderunner/36724cc9ee8db66db305 and try using sample or maybe ecore.

Comment: @torek How can I do this when I don't know the PID of a process that only lasts 5s

Comment: It's a bit problematic. You could start the op and hit ^Z really fast to find the pid. Another possible option: `trace` or `dtrace` (I've never used it, nor any of the other MacOS tools really, I've used strace on Linux and ktrace on BSD and some variants of DTrace but not on MacOS).

Comment: Mine is even worse `git status  0,74s user 39,25s system 966% cpu 4,137 total`. But I have company mac with some antiviruses and stuff...

Comment: Yes I have company Mac as well.

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský, I'm seeing similar behavior. Did you figure if the high system cpu usage is due to antivirus softwares?

Comment: I experienced something simillar: `git status  0.14s user 14.91s system 1073% cpu 1.402 total`, but I removed an app called an app called Confer, which seems related to anti-virus, it's back to normal `git status  0.13s user 0.46s system 156% cpu 0.374 total`. I wonder how an antivirus app would interfere with `git status` though.

Comment: Yeah, it was Microsoft ATP on my side (antivirus). When I delete it, it is quick again. I think antivirus has some kernel hooks and listens to every disk event. `git status` checks all your project files for modification and antivirus probably interfere, making it slow.